# How to use command 'gd' in NetBeans+jVi?

Tags: vim, netbeans

As you may know, `gd` command is very useful and efficient in Vim. But after installing jVi to NetBeans, I found that `gd` is not available. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
NetBeans supports g# or g*, but doesn't support gd. However, to typing gd is more convenient.
But as mentioned below, gd has different meaning from g*, so maybe I could use another self-defined name gs (goto same word)

So go to NetBeans -> Tools -> Options -> jVi Config -> Map Commands, and add below item:

```
map gs g*
```

That's it.

Comment: `g#` is not equivalent to `gd` at all. `gd` is not "more convenient" than `g*` or `g#`: they are entirely different and serve different purposes.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference of them. My meaning is to type * or # I need to press both keys 'Shift' and '*' or '#'. So from this point, I said typing gd is more convenient.

Comment: Well, you could also use `eh` or `,;` or whatever is more convenient for you.

Answer (score 2):

For gd you can use Ctrl-] .

```
map gd <C-]>
```

should do what you want. Though Ctrl-] might be easier

The Ctrl-] command is handled by NetBeans and not with a tags file. This will be exact.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work For me either. You may want to check `g#`, it searches backward in your file. ( `g*` searches forward )
Also Netbeans itself can show you the declarations. you can use that.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans is a powerful IDE, whatever variation on the "jump to declaration" theme it has will always be smarter and more accurate than Vim's.

`<C-b>` is NetBeans "equivalent" of Vim's `gd`.

Comment: `Ctrl-b` is the NetBeans shortcut for "Navigate to declaration" which is *almost* the exact same thing as `gd`. The difference is that NetBeans will jump to the declaration anywhere (local or in some other file) while Vim will only honour local declaration.

Comment: Thank you for this explaination! When enabling jVi, I type Ctrl-b but no 'gd' effect occurs, why?